# How to switch between multiple Values in a cycle?

Tags: variables, count, integer, qml, cycle

I want to switch between multiple values in a cycled kind of way.
For example my variable "Counter" is initialised with 1 and by mouseclick i want it to switch to 2. Another mouseclick will change it to 3 and the next click will repeat the cycle by 1.

How do i do it by using QML?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this a homework question? You should start with showing us what you've tried, and what's not working.

Comment: Never had QML in school but thank you for your statement :) Im just new to QML and try to do stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onClicked{    
switch(counter) {
  case 1:
    counter=2
    break;
  case 2:
    counter=3
    break;
  case 3:
    counter=1
    break;
  default:
    console.log("counter out of rotation)
}
}
```

A switch-case statement should do the trick inside an "onClicked" handler of a button.
You can also do it in many different other ways. Like incrementing counter by +1 each time you press the button and add a if statement that sets counter to 1 again when it reaches the value of 4.

Comment: Thanks :) This is straightforward.

Comment: No Problem :) would be cool if you could mark it as the solution when it fits your needs.

Comment: I chose a different path with state QML type but your answer was definitely useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Button {
    id: button
    readonly property int counterStart: 1
    readonly property int counterEnd: 3
    property int counter: button.counterStart
    onClicked: {
        console.log(button.counter)
        button.counter = Math.max(button.counterStart, ++button.counter % (button.counterEnd + 1))
    }
}
```